# mySQL DISTINCT and SUM

Tags: mysql

I have a table:

[image]

The query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEAST(Message.MesFrom, Message.MesTo) AS user1
      , GREATEST(Message.MesFrom, Message.MesTo) AS user2 
FROM Message 
WHERE MesFrom =1 OR MesTo = 1 
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

The output is users ID's that have messages with userID 1

The next step is:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){if ($row['user1'] == $uid){$userid = $row['user2'];}  else {  $userid = $row['user1']; }echo $userid;
```

So o page i get:
ID
2
4

What I want to do now is count amount of New=1 messages so the output will be

ID  NEW

2    3

4    1

Sorry, dont know how to put table here(

[SQLFiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1d7d8/4)

Comment: +1 for the very easy to use fiddle setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just trying to get `user1` to always have a smaller ID and `user2` to always have a larger ID 
and count the number of new messages between them then this should give you what you want.

```
SELECT user1,user2,sum(new) as newMessages
FROM
  (SELECT 
    LEAST(mesfrom,mesto) as user1,
    GREATEST(mesfrom,mesto) as user2,
    new
   FROM message)as T1
GROUP BY user1,user2
```

[sqlFiddle code](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1d7d8/23/0)

this can be simplified down to

```
SELECT
    LEAST(mesfrom,mesto) as user1,
    GREATEST(mesfrom,mesto) as user2,
    sum(new) as newMessages
FROM
    message
GROUP BY user1,user2
```

[sqlFiddle code simplified](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1d7d8/24/0)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  mesto, sum(new)
FROM Message 
group by mesto
```

Comment: It will give the output of only MesTo fields, but I need both oа MesTo and MesFrom with no duplicates in IDs The next thing I do is: while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { if ($row['user1'] == $uid){ $userid = $row['user2']; } else { $userid = $row['user1']; } echo $userid

Comment: Say exactly what you need in question. Also say exactly what should be the desired result from provided data, its unclear why your result set only has 2 rows.

Comment: Updated question. I need a therd row with sum of New=1

Comment: I still don't understand what you're asking for :(

Comment: I don't know the reason why you're using `LEAST` and `GREATEST` either unless you're trying to get back a row that has [user1,user2] as [1,2] to represent both where [mesto,mesfrom] with values [1,2] and [2,1]

Answer (score 1):

This should return results you want

```
SELECT MesTo, SUM(new) AS NewMessages
FROM Message
GROUP BY MesTo
```

Comment: It will give the output of only MesTo fields, but I need both oа MesTo and MesFrom with no duplicates in IDs

The next thing I do is:
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  if ($row['user1'] == $uid){
  $userid = $row['user2'];
  }
  else {
 $userid = $row['user1'];  
  }

echo $userid